# Accented Chars in HTML email

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following form elements in a Spanish language website (ASP.Net MVC3)
(truncated, of course)

```
<label for="RazonSocial">Raz&oacute;n Social</label>
<input type="text" id="RazonSocial" name="RazonSocial" class="span12"  value=""/>
<label class="radio" for="razon_social_emp">Empresa
    <input type="radio" name="Razon_Social" id="razon_social_emp" value="Empresa" />
</label>
<label class="radio" for="razon_social_pf">Persona F&iacute;sica
    <input type="radio" name="Razon_Social" id="razon_social_pf" value="Persona Física" />
</label>
```

Now, I'm sending those values in an HTML email using this model:
(truncated, of course)

```
public class RegistrationEmailModel
{
    public string RazonSocial { get; set; }

    public string Razon_Social { get; set; }
}
```

This is the email view:
(truncated, of course)

```
@model MyNamespace.Models.RegistrationEmailModel
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body { font-family:"Lucida Grande",verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:11px;}
            .h3 {color:#CC6600; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px;}
            .header { margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 5px; text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #C6600; }
            .p10 { font-size 11px; margin-top: 3px; margin-bottom: 3px;}
            .rt {text-align: right; width: 25%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width="660px" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="rt">
                    <span class="p10">Razón Social:&nbsp;</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="p10"><b>@Model.RazonSocial</b></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="rt">
                    <span class="p10">Tipo de Raz&oacute;n Social:&nbsp;</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="p10"><b>@RazonSocial</b></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The issue I'm having is that the value of the Razon_Social radio button does not come over in the email with the accented char.
How can I convert that to properly send the accented char in the email?

**Edit:**
Here's the RenderPartialViewToString() function:

```
public static string RenderPartialViewToString(Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
{
    controller.ViewData.Model = model;
    try
    {
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Email is only form data.

Comment: Is your text coming for the database?

Comment: No, it is coming from the form at the top of my post. Nothing is coming from or going to a database. The system is essentially a website form that the user fills in and then when they click a button, it emails the filled form data that got put into a model using a typed Razor view

Comment: So, data is fine on post back(when you put a break point in your controller) but the email you send does not show Spanish properly. Is that correct?

Comment: It comes over to the Model perfectly, then gets put into the email view and I use the RenderPartialViewToString() function to put it into the body of the email, It doesn't show correctly in the email. Maybe I should check there to see if it is converting to string correctly in that function?

Comment: Seems it is not going to the Model as I thought. However, I wrote code to set it correctly in the Model. But the RenderPartialViewToString() function is still messing it up. I'll post that code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using ActionMailer.Net (http://geeksharp.com/2011/01/26/actionmailer-net-email-templates-for-the-mvc-crowd/) and wrote an OnMailSending() handler to replace the offending character. I am not sure if any other characters will cause an issue but at least it works for now. I will keep monitoring.

OnMailSending() handler in my MailController:

```
protected override void OnMailSending(MailSendingContext context)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < context.Mail.AlternateViews.Count; i++)
    {
        var av = context.Mail.AlternateViews[i];
        if (av.ContentType.MediaType == MediaTypeNames.Text.Html)
        {
            av.ContentStream.Position = 0;
            var content = new StreamReader(av.ContentStream).ReadToEnd();
            content = content.Replace("F?sica", "Fí­sica");
            context.Mail.AlternateViews[i] = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(content, av.ContentType);
        }
    }            
    base.OnMailSending(context);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the utf-8 meta header to your email template.

If you are using HTML5:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

or if you are using HTML 4:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

By the way specify what you are using with a proper DOCTYPE field. For example for HTML5 that would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Oh and by the way, a bit off topic, but radio buttons in an email? Really? What for?

Comment: Radio buttons ARE NOT in the email, only the data from the form.

Comment: Tried all three and it is coming over "Persona F??sica"